# How i can compare the value of an id with java

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a simple xml with a question and two buttons. When one of buttons is pushed i will compare if the id of the pushed button is equal to "Blanco" or "Negro".
The XML code:

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textView1"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:gravity="center"
>         android:text="@string/pregunta" />
>
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/button1"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/Blanco" 
>             android:onClick="respuesta"/>
>
>         <Button
>             android:id="@+id/button2"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:text="@string/Negro" 
>             android:onClick="respuesta"/>
>
>     </LinearLayout>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

This is de java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void respuesta(){
        //The doubt.
        //Here the if/else to compare ID with the button text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

implement onClickListener into your Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
```

Declare the Button variables inside your class

```
Button btblanco, btnegro;
```

Implement the clickListener event on onCreate

```
btblanco = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnegro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

btblanco.setOnClickListener(this);

btnegro.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And put this inside onClickListener method.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {

        case R.id.button1:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Blanco", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

        case R.id.button2:

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Negro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;


    }}
```

Comment: Sorry, but i´m noob in android. To which onClickListener method do you mean?

Comment: Very nearly!! An error appears in onClick. The error says: void is an invalid type for the variable onClick. I put the onClick method within onClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it like that. Create an `onClickListener` for each `Button`, so you know exactly which one is being pressed. For example:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // call code here, knowing that button1 was pressed
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // call code here, knowing that button2 was pressed
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in just knowing which button was clicked, then add a onclicklistener to the button objects. Google for it a bit and the samples you find will show you how to use a switch case structure to d actions based on which button was clicked.